# Formatting boolean values in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have datagridview which display table data at runtime,some of the columns in table are having data type boolean.But at the runtime check boxes are getting displayed on the datagirdview,i need to show true or false value instead of check box.can any one give me proper solution..?

Comment: You need to add a text box column yourself and bind it by setting its `DataPropertyName` and then, I think, handle the `CellFormatting` event of the grid to display the appropriate text.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting value in boolean field to string data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dtb As New DataTable
dtb.Columns.Add("C1", GetType(String))
dtb.Columns.Add("C2", GetType(Boolean))
dtb.Rows.Add("A", True)
dtb.Rows.Add("B", False)
dtb.Rows.Add("C", True)
dtb.Rows.Add("D", False)
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.DataPropertyName = "C1"})
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.DataPropertyName = "C2"})
DataGridView1.DataSource = dtb
```